# > install.packages("ElmStatLearn")

Tags: r

```r
> install.packages("ElmStatLearn")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/RSR/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘ElmStatLearn’ is not available for this version of R
```

How to resolve this issue? any guidance will be apprecitaed.

Comment: Did you mean `ElemStatLearn`?

Comment: Google for [`CRAN ElmStatLearn`](https://www.google.com/search?q=CRAN+ElmStatLearn) and you'll get a [link at CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ElemStatLearn/index.html) that says that that package *"was removed from the CRAN repository"*. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25721884/3358272 for some alternatives, including (1) look in CRAN's archive to download older version; (2) install from github; (3) `remotes::install_version(...)`; or possibly something else.

Comment: Yes I meant ElemStatLearn. sorry fot typo.